# transparent box over title

Tags: css, background, html

Now, I've tried a lot of different ways in a CSS Plugin (the homepage works via Wordpress) to get the "box" transparent (but not the text obviously) so it won't interfere with the title anymore. I tried opacity, .png. It seems I can't really hit the needed class or ID.

How can I make this transparent so you can hover over the header, you just see the text and this white box doesn't cover the title. Any help appreciated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

it is your

```
.main-navigation ul ul a
```

set it on

```
background: transparent;
```

and it works

Comment: No problem, i would appreciate if you mark that my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your main CSS file make this selector .main-navigation ul ul a to background-color: transparent; just like below.

```
.main-navigation ul ul a {
   background-color: transparent;
}
```